# Whats wrong with my code below for obtaining string length using pointers?

Tags: c, string, pointers

If the line "n=str_len(s);" is commented, n is printed, else it just compiles, but when run, nothing happens. Need help understanding what is missing here. Thanks.

```
// C Program to get string length
#include<stdio.h>
//int str_len(char *s);
int str_len(char *s){
  printf("in function");
  char *c =s;
  while(c!='\0')
    c++;
  return c-s;
}

int main(){
  char *s="Hello World";
  int n=0;
  //printf("n = %d",n);
  //printf("String :%s\n",*s);
  n = str_len(s);
  //printf("String :%s",*s);
  printf("Length :%d\n",n);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `while(c!='\0')` --> `while(*c != '\0')`?

Comment: It is very helpful to enable compiler warnings and make them all go away.

Comment: Note: when debugging with `printf`, be sure to put a newline `\n` at the end of every format string. The *"in function"* message was being printed. If you didn't see it, it was because it got stuck in a buffer waiting for a newline character.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Not comparing what `c` points to.

   ```
   // while(c!='\0')
   while(*c != '\0')
   ```
2. Wrong type.  Use `size_t`. `int` maybe insufficient.  All array sizes, and so *string* lengths,  fit in `size_t`.

   ```
   // int str_len(char *s){
   size_t str_len(char *s){
   ```
3. `strlen()` works with `const char *`

All together

```
size_t str_len(const char *s) {
  // printf("in function");
  const char *c = s;
  while(*c) {
    c++;
  }
  return (size_t) (c - s);
}
```

Ref `size_t strlen(const char *s);`  C11 §7.23.6.3  1

Comment: Thanks. It worked.I have couple of questions, 1. what does size_t mean? 2. what is the importance of using a const for char?

Comment: @Learner12 `size_t` is a type, an _unsigned integer_ type.  Its at _least_ 16-bits.  As answered, it is sufficient to hold all possible answers from `strlen()`.

Comment: @Learner12 Let us narrow this.  What about `const` that is unclear  in your learner resources?

Comment: Thanks @chux.  It helps me to pursue further about size_t. Wrt const, I find the code running even without const. So, just want to be sure about the cases, it will help.

Comment: @Learner12 " I find the code running even without const" --> Hmmm.  I suspect only a few cases were run.   What is your understanding of what `const` is for?

Comment: To define something that doesn't change. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Learner12 `strlen(const char * s)` means `s` is a pointer to data that it will not change.  So `strlen(const char * s)` can be called with `const char *` and `char *` pointers.  Defined behavior for `strlen_x(char * s)` can only be called with `char *` pointers.  Another benefit `foo1(const char * s1, const char * s2)` can create more optimized code than `foo2(char * s1, char * s2)`.